# android opengl texture overlapping

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

i am following [nehe's tutorials](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/). 
i intent to make a menu or at least buttons with opengl, yet object overlap on the menu

[image: this is objects in the center with menu buttons on the right below]

[image: when menu buttons gets in the overlapping]
my code on the drawFrame function in the renderer

```
gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glScalef(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, z-zKonum);
    gl.glRotatef(xAcisi, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(yAcisi, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    dokukup.ciz(gl);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(3.6f, -1.5f, z);
    tusYukari.ciz(gl);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(2.5f, -1.5f, z);
    tusAsagi.ciz(gl);
```

how do i get my menu buttons dominant(always on the top) on the overlapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the buttons to appear always on top by drawing the buttons last and disabling depth testing when drawing the buttons. Then make sure to enable depth testing again before drawing the next frame so that your 3D geometry renders properly.

In your drawFrame function you would do the following steps:

1. Enable depth testing
2. Draw the main scene geometry
3. Disable depth testing
4. Draw the buttons

Comment: in the draw function of tus add 
first 
     
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
to the last of the function 
       gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);